# How does one traceout for which actual interface/instance connection was established via AWS NAT GW?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Situation:

- VPC flow logs which are forwarded to the SIEM reflect communication from the NAT GW and the public IP address.

Problem:

- VPC flow logs in the SIEM do not show what internal instance was involved in the communication.

Question:

- What AWS dataset from the perspective of a log aggregator, if it has a name, do I need to look for if I do not have access to the actual AWS account and I want to view the responsible instance?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I either misread your question or are you really trying to ask us how to get information, which isn't logged? Also, you might have a permissions issue (a.k.a. it might be impoosible to accomplish) but then again I'm not an AWS expert...

Comment: VPC flow logs show IP addresses. The only way I know to find the instance name, off the top of my head, is to use the AWS API to request the instance information for each instance and populate your data set. There may be a reverse lookup API call, have a look in the API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html